# VS Code: "Import Error: No module named request" although it's installed

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, pip, virtualenv

To build a web scraping program in python 3 I do the following

```
import urllib.request
```

I use a venv, which is selcted and shown on the bottom left in VS Code. The `settings.json` file has:

```
"python.pythonPath": "venv/bin/python"
```

Also the integrated terminal has been closed and reopened multiple times. Entering `pip list` shows `request` as installed for that venv.

If I run the file no problems come up but in output it keeps saying

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/filepath/filename.py", line 2, in 
<module>
import urllib.request
ImportError: No module named request
```

**Important:** The last time I had this file open, everything was fine with importing that module. Now after saving and reopening that project next day I keep getting this error message over and over again.

I really hope someone can help! Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour]. That error message doesn't seem to match that code. Please post the full error message with traceback. You can [edit] the question. Also make sure to use [code formatting](/editing-help#code) for code and preformatted text.

Answer (score 0):

One of two things is occurring. One is that your environment is actually Python 2 and not Python 3 as `urllib.request` only exists in the latter (you can check this by looking in the lower-left of your screen in the status bar). The other possibility is you created a file named `urllib` in your own code and that's shadowing the `urllib` package in the stdlib. You can verify this by changing your code to `import urllib; print(urllib.__file__)`. If that prints out a path to one of your files then rename that file and it should fix your issue.

You don't need to change your import line from `import urllib.request`; that's basically the same as `from urllib import request` but lets you use a different name to get at the same module.

Also note that `urllib.request` is included in Python 3 itself, so it won't show up in a call to `pip list`. I suspect you're thinking of `requests` which is a different package and accessible via `import requests`.

Comment: Thank you Brett for your detailed answer! I double checked both options, no file named urllib and I am using Python 3 to run the program. I tried now to open my code in IDLE instead and it runs without problems. Maybe the issue is with VS Code and the way it is installed on my Mac. Hopefully I figure it out at some point ;)

Comment: Can you print out `urllib.__file__` and `sys.version_info` and share that here?

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, welcome to Stack Overflow!
This looks like an issue with how you imported request from urllib. Could you please try changing the import to this instead:

```
from urllib import request
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks! Now I am getting back "ImportError: cannot import name request"

Comment: Possibly a bit late but is urllib installed with pip @JulieCate?